# I want to copy a value from excel sheet and paste it in a search box of a web page . Any Help appreciated

Tags: python, excel

```
import openpyxl 

rs= openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\PYT\\Read.xlsx")

kj = rs['Sheet1']
print(kj['A3'].value)
```

The above code is written just to print the data

I have used selenium to automate the browser which opens a web page , now the challenge for me is i want the data which i am copying from the excel file is to be searched on that website.

Comment: do you have a public API or something like this to search on the website or do you mean finding a string in a html file?

Comment: for example i have a excel file which contains data in cells , i want cell A1 data to be copied and paste in a search box of a website rather typing it manually  . code for opening the browser working fine.

Comment: I don't get your problem. You got the search string, you got the browser. To me it seems your problem is more selenium related than the python/excel part.